# Run one ansible playbook task on localhost, and then another task on remote server

Tags: ansible

I am playing with automating our VMware deployment and configurations and have run in to a question I can't find the answer for on google.

To start, I am running a playbook task on localhost that reaches out to vsphere to provision my server.  After that in the same playbook I want to reach out to the provisioned server and make a few configuration changes to finish up.  How can I do this?  Right now my playbook looks like:

```
- hosts:
    - localhost
  tasks:
  - name:  Clone a virtual machine from Linux template and customize
    vmware_guest:
      hostname: "VSphere"
      username: "Username"
      password: "Password"
      validate_certs: no
      datacenter: "DC"
      state: present
      folder: /Servers
      template: "MyTemplate"
      name: "{{ServerName}}"
      cluster: "Prod Cluster"
      networks:
        - name: VM Network
          ip: "{{IP}}"
          netmask: 255.255.255.0
          gateway: "{{Gateway}}"
      wait_for_ip_address: True
      customization:
        domain: "mydomain.com"
        dns_servers:
          - 192.168.1.1
          - 192.168.1.2
        dns_suffix:
          - mydomain.com
    delegate_to: localhost

  - name:  Register VM to Satellite
     #here is where I need to know how to specify running commands on my specific IP(which I pass in on command line as var)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the add_host module to the new host to your inventory, and then target that host in another play (you don't need that `delegate_to: localhost` in your task, because you're already targeting `localhost` in the play):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name:  Clone a virtual machine from Linux template and customize
      vmware_guest:
        hostname: "VSphere"
        username: "Username"
        password: "Password"
        validate_certs: no
        datacenter: "DC"
        state: present
        folder: /Servers
        template: "MyTemplate"
        name: "{{ServerName}}"
        cluster: "Prod Cluster"
        networks:
          - name: VM Network
            ip: "{{IP}}"
            netmask: 255.255.255.0
            gateway: "{{Gateway}}"
        wait_for_ip_address: True
        customization:
          domain: "mydomain.com"
          dns_servers:
            - 192.168.1.1
            - 192.168.1.2
          dns_suffix:
            - mydomain.com

      - name: add host to inventory
        add_host:
          name: new_host
          ansible_host: "{{ IP }}"
          groups: vms

- hosts: vms
  tasks:
    - name: register vm to satellite
      ...
```

You could also do this through the use of a [dynamic inventory plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory.html#inventory-plugins); there is one available for vmware.

Comment: Thank you much, this worked perfectly/was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know what your IP address is, just put that in your inventory.  In fact, you can have as many as you want.  You'll have `hosts: all` ( not localhost).  If the VM already exists, nothing will happen in the `vmware_guest` call.  (And you already have the vCenter call delegated to `localhost`.)

You will want to put in a `wait_for`, to give the VM time to come up before you try to register it.